# If i am getting the doc file using javascript and sending it to external server it is showing weird text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am sending a file to an external server using ajax and api.I attached a file and then when i clicked on the upload button. It gets the content of the file and then send it to the external server using it's API. The request must be in json otherwise it rejects the data

Below are my code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_submit_new_resume" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="file" name="textfile" id="textfile">
<input type="button" onclick="submitform()">
</form>
```

Below is my javascript file

```
function submitform(){
var filesSelected = document.getElementById("textfile").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0)
    {   document.getElementById('loading').style.display="block";
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {
            var textAreaFileContents = document.getElementById
            (
                "textAreaFileContents"
            );

            var fileName = fileToLoad.name;
            var base64encode = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;

            jQuery.ajax(

{

url : "https://api.resumatorapi.com/v1/applicants",

type: 'POST',

dataType : "json",
 contentType : "application/json",

data: '{"apikey":"apikey", "resumetext" : "'+base64encode+'"}',

}

)
}
```

It successfully upload the file but when i see the file on server then it is showing invalid file.[image]

If i use php's inbuilt function get_file_content then it is showing the correct text but i want to do it through ajax.Is there any other way to get the exact content of a doc file using jquery or javascript?

Comment: are you able to get proper formatted data before sending

Comment: Nope it is sending the same data which is appeared on the image, is there any other way to get the content data using jquery or ajax?

Comment: if you are using php then yes...for that you need make two calls one ajax call to upload file on some location(local/whatever) and onSubmit call php function to get data from uploaded file and submit that data to your API call. Hope this will help you somehow

Comment: You should perhaps use [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString), so that you get the binary image data, instead of a Data URI.